# How do I access the settings in first time wizard in E17?

Tags: enlightenment

... and other settings in general. I want to change the behavior of the mouse when hover on an icon, it will highlight instead of click (which is available from firs time setup). Also, I enable the effects, which is quite heavy for my machine and I want to turn it off. Where to adjust it?

I've just installed E17, so I'm still new to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

E17/Enlightenment settings are accessed by clicking on the desktop and choosing 'Settings/Settings Panel' from the menu. The help page describing this is on their wiki page here: http://trac.enlightenment.org/e/wiki/Configuration